# Save multiple images with one function - AS3 ADOBE AIR

Tags: image, actionscript-3, air

I've got an Array with 17 web links of images

```
        var products:Array;
        trace(products) 

 // Ouput : 
"http://www.myWebsite.com/zootopia.jpg"
"http://www.myWebsite.com/james.jpg"
"http://www.myWebsite.com/tom.jpg"
    ..etc
```

If I do `products[10].movieimage;` the output will be the 9th link (something like : `"http://www.myWebsite.com/lalaland.jpg"`)

I'm looking for downloading every images without a dialog box.

I manage to do so for 1 image with the specific link, like that :

```
function saveImage (event:Event):void {

 var stream:URLStream = new URLStream(); 
 var image1:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("test.jpg"); 
 var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream(); 

stream.load(new URLRequest("http://www.myWebsite.com/lalaland.jpg")); 
stream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, writeComplete); 
        

 function writeComplete(evt:Event):void  { 
                var fileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
                stream.readBytes(fileData,0,stream.bytesAvailable); 
                fileStream.openAsync(image1, FileMode.UPDATE); 
                fileStream.writeBytes(fileData,0,fileData.length); 
                fileStream.close(); 
                 trace("writeComplete");
                 trace(image1.url); 
        } 
}
```

**Question : Is there a way to download all the images with the web links of my `products` array ?** (and if images already exist, replace them. I could use `if (image1.exists){` `if (image2.exists){` ..etc for each image. But maybe there is a simplier solution)

If you could show me how, with a bit of code, I could that.

Also, note that I'd like to load the images then in `Uiloader`, like that :

```
    function loadImages():void {
uiloader1.source = image1.url;
uiloader2.source = image2.url;
etc...
    }
```

Comment: I think `For` loops might help you to do **repeat instructions** over multiple iterations (_ie:_ the image total). See this [**Adobe article**](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/loops.html). Ask here when stuck & show the problem code with error(s).

Comment: Thx for the answer. I read the article. It tells me how to repeat instructions indeed but it doesn't tell me how to save each image with a different name (like image1, then image2..etc). Because if I do `while(products.movieimage< 18) { saveImage(); }` as it will repeat the function saveImage eachh time and replacing my "`test.jpg`" file.

Comment: Just make a `var num:int = 1;` then later when you do IF statement you pass num as function variable `while( stuff < 18) { saveImage(num); }` then inside that function `saveImage` you say `filename = "image" + String(num); num++` where by having `num++` means value of `num` increases by +1 for next usage of `{ saveImage(num); }`...

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try that !

Answer (score 1):

Don't over think it. You have your array of images. You have your tested routine for saving one image. Now put it together:

1. Some function initializes things and kicks it off.
2. Either splice out (or pop out) an item on the array – OR use a index `var` to access an item in the array
3. Pass that to your download function.
4. When the download completes either pop another item off the array OR increment your index. But first you would test if `array.length== 0` OR `index > array.length. If either is true (depending on which method you use), then you are done.
5. If you want to get fancy you can show a progress bar and update it each time your download completes.

Comment: My array contains 18 links. So I could write 18 download functions with, in each function, a different name for the file that is save (image1, image2, image3....image18). But it's gonna be very long and, I think, bad coding. I'm looking for a way to have 1 function that can save all the images of my array containing web link into 18 different files. If you have a sample code to share (not precisely for this project. I understand that he'd take you too much time. But maybe someone had the same questions before me ?? I'd be thrilled if I could have some code.

Comment: @Steph – no, you misunderstand. Think of it like a line or queue of people waiting for a taxi in front of a hotel. That line is your **array**. The taxi is your **download routine**. The hotel doorman checks to see if there are people in line and, if there are, he calls for another taxi... get my drift. As for "giving you some code" – you aren't going to learn that way, are you?

Comment: Thx for the explanation. I'll try to do the code, but I learn AS3 based on sample code. It's been 3 years now and each time I took sample code on forums or website and learn this way. Copy the working code, and read it to learn. Make some modification and see what's happening when I change this or that. It's my way to learn (go from a working code that I change).